# how to get current URL from Browser in API 23?

Tags: android, browser

how to get current URL from Browser in API 23. I tried to use Browser.BookmarkColumns, but it was removed from API 23. thanks in advance

```
public String chromeHistory(){ 
        String[] proj = new String[]{"title","url"};
        Uri uriCustom = Uri.parse("content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks");
        String sel = "bookmark = 0";
        Cursor mCur = getContentResolver().query(uriCustom, proj, sel, null, "date"+" ASC");
        String url = "";
        if (mCur.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                url = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex("url"));
            }while(mCur.moveToNext());
        }
        mCur.close();
        return url;
    }
```

In API 23 it does not return any url, but below API23 it returns browsing url. Please help me. I was struck in this for past one day

Comment: Implement an `ACTION_SEND` activity, for `text/plain`, and have the user share the URL with you through the browser UI.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Thanks man, but for my scenarios it is not working. I need Current URL which i was entered in the browser in Android 6.0(API 23)

Comment: I certainly hope that is no longer possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: ya i understood, but it was able to access in API 22 and below. From API 23 and above, we con't access those bookmark histories. Is there have any alternate solution for this scenario? If yes means, whats that?

Comment: "Is there have any alternate solution for this scenario?" -- I sincerely hope not. If there is, that is a security flaw that I will need to work on getting fixed. You are certainly welcome to write your own Web browser (e.g., using `WebView`), in which case you have complete access to what the user does in that browser.

Comment: When user entered a URL in browser, i need to get that URL from browser and check with my DB.